# Integer linear combinations of coprime integers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider the finite set

$S=\{s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n\}$ such that

$GCF(s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n)=1$.

Show that $\exists n$ such that $n$ cannot be written as

$n=c_1s_1+c_2s_2+\dots+c_ns_n \forall c_i,s_i \in \Bbb N \cup \{0\}$

such that $\forall m>n$, that $m$ can be written in this way.

I'm pretty sure this is correct, because I've written a java program which seems to verify this hypothesis.

```
public class Main 
{

    private final int ARRSIZE = 10000;

    public Main()
    {
        boolean[] members = new boolean[ARRSIZE];
        int[] ints = {5,7}; //input S here
        for(int i : ints)
            members[i] = true;
        for(int i = 1; i < ARRSIZE; i++)
            if(members[i])
                for(int j : ints)
                    if(i + j < ARRSIZE)
                        members[i + j] = true;
        //go through the array and print the remaining values
        for(int i = 1; i < ARRSIZE; i++)
            if(!members[i])
                System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main m = new Main();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Certainly every large enough $m$ can be so written.  If $1$ is one of the $s_i$, all non-negative integers can be so written.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be similar to the [Coin Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) which considers making change and finding a greatest value that can't be produced.